# Understanding waypoints basics

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use the popular "Waypoints" jQuery library. I've looked at various examples and documentation but I am struggling to grasp how to access the element attached to the waypoint.

To make it clearer I have several sections of the page belonging to the `.nudgedown` class. I'd like to have them change background color once scrolled to. I am trying to see if anything is working at all by alerting their initial background color with this code:

```
$(".nudgedown").waypoint(function(){
    alert($(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

However nothing happens and in the console I get this error:

> TypeError: b.ownerDocument is undefined

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something conceptually in my approach? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Rory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you try to get the wrong element with `$(this)`. You can try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var waypoints = $('.nudgedown').waypoint({
              handler: function(direction) {
              var el=$(this).get(0).element;
              console.log($(el).css("background-color"));
            }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:blue; height:50px"></div>
<span class="nudgedown" style="background-color:red;">test</span>
<div style="background-color:green; height:800px"></div>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you Quentin! It's definitely working but I don't understand this bit: $(this).get(0).element

Comment: $(this) is an array of waypoints,  with get(0) you get the first waypoint objet that contains the dom element

Comment: does the array contains all the elements with class ".nudgedown"?